# Implicit class method not found

Tags: scala, implicit

I have an object with an implicit class:

```
object ModelUtils {
  implicit class RichString(str: String) {
    def isNullOrEmpty(x: String): Boolean = x == null || x.trim.isEmpty
  }
}
```

However, when I try to use it, IntelliJ cannot find the isNullOrEmpty method:

```
"TestString".isNullOrEmpty
```

I've tried various imports to import the method to no avail. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is probably not with the import itself, but rather with the unnecessary parameter `x`. If you want to call `.isNullOrEmpty` without any arguments, then you must use `str`, not `x`:

```
object ModelUtils {
  implicit class RichString(str: String) {
    def isNullOrEmpty: Boolean = str == null || str.trim.isEmpty
  }
}

import ModelUtils._

println("TestString".isNullOrEmpty)
```